# Flake8 failing to detect syntax issues that can be detect by pyflakes

Tags: flake8, pyflakes

I am trying to get Emacs' flycheck to work nicely with python syntax error checking. By default it uses flake8, but I noticed that recently flake8 is only reporting style issues, when it supposed to produce the same kind of results as pyflakes.

As an example, I have a simple python script with a wrong module name.

```
$ cat so.py

import os

print(os.path)

op.path()
```

output of `$ flake8 so.py` is empty, while pyflakes' output is

```
 $ pyflakes so.py

 so.py:5: undefined name 'op'
```

My flake8 configuration, if it matters:

```
[flake8]
max-line-length = 96
ignore = E123,E701,E126,F821
```

I am using Linux, if that matters.

Flake8 version: version 3.3.0 mccabe: 0.6.1, pycodestyle: 2.3.1, pyflakes: 1.5.0

Pyflakes version: 1.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're wondering why Flake8 isn't reporting something you think it should, the best path forward is to utilize the `--isolated` flag.

With the file contents above in `ex.py` if I do:

```
❯❯❯ flake8 --isolated ex.py
ex.py:5:1: F821 undefined name 'op'
```

With that in mind, it does appear that your configuration is the problem here.